# Is there a way to auto-join conversations in multiplayer?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

When playing multiplayer in Baldur's Gate 3, is there any way to automatically join conversations initiated by another player? Or alternatively, can I add some sort of audio cue when there's a conversation I can join? I find myself missing the start of conversations because I don't notice the "listen" icon right away.

[image: Listen icon]

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can just rejoin the group (a party can still be split up into groups). There's also the check box that appears when you're looking in on someone else in a conversation.

Comment: A few comments in Reddit threads mention [this mod, 'baldurs-gate-3-auto-join-conversation' by user seyahdoo](https://github.com/seyahdoo/baldurs-gate-3-auto-join-conversation/releases/tag/v1.0.2), an application to run before starting the game. I'm a little hesitant to just run an executable file like that, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option to auto-join conversations was added in [Patch 3 on September 22, 2023](https://baldursgate3.game/news/patch-3-mac-support-magic-mirror-more_93). It can be found under *Options > Gameplay > Default Online Settings > Eavesdrop*.

> Added an option to the Default Online Settings to let you automatically listen in when another party member enters a dialogue in multiplayer.

[image]